# How to retrieve the content of returned list collection from a static class

Tags: c#, list, static, return

How can I get each element (firstname, lastname) of the customer class which is assigned in customers in Main. I am not able to do `customers.firstname` in main.

```
public static class CustomerProvider
{
    public static List<Customer> GetRandomCustomers()
    {
        var result = new List<Customer>();
        var customer1 = new Customer();
        customer1.FirstName = "Tony";
        customer1.LastName = "Romo";
        customer1.DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime("03 / 10 / 88");
        result.Add(customer1);

        return result;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var customers=  CustomerProvider.GetRandomCustomers();

        foreach (var c in customers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(customers);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand what your `foreach` is doing.

`customers` is your collection of the `Customer` class and `c` is a single different `Customer` each time through the loop.

So you will write it like this:

```
foreach (var c in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName);
    Console.WriteLine(c.LastName);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was lost, not finding that simple glitch in "foreach". Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
foreach (var c in customers)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName);
      Console.WriteLine(c.LastName);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach, you're writing out the wrong variable:

```
    foreach (var c in customers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
foreach (var c in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName );
    Console.WriteLine(c.LastName );
    Console.WriteLine(c.DateOfBirth );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via `c` foreach variable.

```
foreach (var c in customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.FirstName);
}
```